# Undefined param of filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a filter in AngularJS but when I try to represent value in the view with this filter, I get undefined x.

My code:

```
.filter('param', function() {
    return function(x) {
        console.log(x);
        return x.split('__')[0];
    };
})
```

view

```
{{value | param}}
```

Result

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

I suspect it is that when loading the page I still do not have the value because it is obtained from a promise.

Comment: What is `value` ? Can you share it here ?

Comment: value is a attribute of $scope that get by promise.

Comment: It probably isn't initialized yet when the filter first kicks of, as you say that value is resolved by a promise. This means that value first is `undefined`, and you cannot run `.split` on undefined. Just do a check in your filter: `if(!x) return x`

Comment: It is indeed that. I add if(!x), Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
.filter('param', function() {
    return function(x) {
        if(x && typeof x === "string") return x.split('__')[0];
        else return x;
    };
})
```

**Explanation** :

You can apply the split function only of `x` has some value, in other terms, when `x` is not `null` or `undefined`.

Hence, we add a check to validate the variable `x`

Comment: `if(x)` only checks, if the value is truthy. if `x` is e.g. `1`, it will crash.

Comment: Right. But I'm sure value is a string. Anyway I used ngClock to wait for values to have value.

Comment: You can never be sure :) Words of experience !